# How do I make a animated floating background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am working on a project and I need the background of the login view to look like it is floating. Right now I have a relative layout with an ImageView filling the screen and am trying to use an animation set to make it work. My problem is that I cannot get the background image to be larger than the screen. When it moves, it was cropped by the screen edges. Here is the animation set that has gotten me the closest to what I want:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1.2" android:fromYScale="1.2"
           android:toXScale="1.2" android:toYScale="1.2"
           android:pivotX="50%"  android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="4"
            android:fillAfter="true"/>
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-10%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="1000"/>
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-10%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="1000"/>
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="10%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="2000"/>
    <translate android:fromXDelta="10%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="3000"
            android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```

I have this set repeating with an animation listener and when it repeats, it is not smooth. The scale animation flickers back to the original image size and starts again.

I have tried playing with the scaletype of the ImageView but have not gotten the correct combination. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!